# How can I modify my sampling rate using methods other than DMA?

Tags: python

The ADC module [PmodAD1](https://designspark-pmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/DesignSpark/Pmod/AD1.html#PmodAD1)
I am currently using with 1M sampling rate and 12bit resolution
I use spidev as a library to connect to ADC
But it seems that he can only sample up to a sampling rate of 20KSPS
I want a sample rate of at least 384Ksps

Is there a way to achieve my desired sampling rate other than using DMA?

Because it needs to cooperate with other software, that software is compiled using python
So hope to be able to achieve 384Ksps without using c

Comment: Not sure exactly what you need or what resources you have available to you. Take a look at the PIC24F family of processors and use it as a peripheral chip. They appear do do what you want. Use it as a A/D converter, it has fifo buffering 32 deep, and with some coding you could save the results in the internal ram as well and read the results as fast as you want.

Comment: I want to do it as much as possible without external hardware
Is there any way to use bcm2835 to control GPIO, or to modify spidev.so to improve my ADC sampling speed

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with that Broadcom chip.

Comment: Ok still thank you very much for your answer